# Zero padding a 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, padding, zero-padding

I currently have an issue with zero padding my 2d Array. I want to transfer my current data in my array to a new array, which is the exact same array but with a border of 0's around it.
Example:

|1 2 3|

|4 5 6|

|7 8 9|

Should become

|0 0 0 0 0|

|0 1 2 3 0|

|0 4 5 6 0|

|0 7 8 9 0|

|0 0 0 0 0|

```
 int[,] Array = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 } };
        
        int[,] ArrayZeroPad = new int[Array.GetLength(0) + 2, Array.GetLength(1) + 2];
        for (int y = 0; y < Array.GetLength(1); y++)
        {

            for (int x = 0; x < ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                if (y == 0)
                { ArrayZeroPad[y, x] = 0; }
                else if (y == ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(1))
                { ArrayZeroPad[y, x] = 0; }
                else if (x == 0)
                {
                    ArrayZeroPad[y, x] = 0;

                }
                else if (x == ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(0))
                { ArrayZeroPad[y, x] = 0; }
                else ArrayZeroPad[y, x] = Array[y, x];
            }
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int x = 0; x < ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(0); x++)
            { Console.Write(ArrayZeroPad[y, x]); }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

This is what I have come to thus far, but I keep getting stuck on out of bounds errors, is there anyone who could work this out for me with some explanation?

Kind regards,
D.

Comment: You should just be able to change your loop range to whatever your padding length is and archive good results. Consider using `for(int y = paddingSize; y < ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(1) - paddingSize; y++)`

Comment: If you wanted to be creative, you could do this without copying.  Just get a class that it handed an array of T and has a `public T this [int][int]` implementation that makes it look like an array X+2 by Y+2 that has zeros (default values) all the way around

Comment: In the last line of your inner loop you are trying to access memory outside of the bounds of `Array`. The dimensions of `ArrayZeroPad` are longer than those of `Array` but you are indexing up to the lengths of `ArrayZeroPad`'s dimensions. When `x` or `y` goes to a value longer than the length of a dimension of `Array` you are out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        int[,] Array = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 } };
        int[,] ArrayZeroPad = new int[Array.GetLength(0) + 2, Array.GetLength(1) + 2];

        for (int x = 0; x < ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                //First row and last row
                if (x == 0 || x == ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(0) - 1)
                    ArrayZeroPad[x, y] = 0;
                else
                {
                    //Fist column and last column
                    if (y == 0 || y == ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(0) - 1)
                        ArrayZeroPad[x, y] = 0;
                    else
                    {
                        //Content
                        ArrayZeroPad[x, y] = Array[x-1, y-1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This did the trick, thank you!

Comment: You don't actually need to set `0`s manually.

Comment: You are right, It's just for clarity and explanation purposes

Comment: Would you know of a way to expand this where I can choose how thick the border needs to be?

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite what you are asking (I thought a completely different alternative would be interesting).

Here is a **No-Copy** version that works for any type of array, of any size.  It's appropriate if the original array is quite large (since it doesn't require a copy).

It uses a 2-dimensional indexer that either returns the default value of T (zero or null) for items on the edge, and uses the original array (with the indexes offset) for non-edge values:

```
public class ZeroPadArray <T>
{
    private readonly T[,] _initArray;

    public ZeroPadArray(T[,] arrayToPad)
    {
        _initArray = arrayToPad;
    }

    public T this[int i, int j]
    {
        get
        {
            if (i < 0 || i > _initArray.GetLength(0) + 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(i),
                    $@"Index {nameof(i)} must be between 0 and the width of the padded array");
            }
            if (j < 0 || j > _initArray.GetLength(1) + 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(j),
                    $@"Index {nameof(j)} must be between 0 and the width of the padded array");
            }

            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            if (i == _initArray.GetLength(0) + 1)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            if (j == _initArray.GetLength(1) + 1)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            //otherwise, just offset into the original array
            return _initArray[i - 1, j - 1];
        }
    }
}
```

I just tested it with some `Debug.Assert` calls.  The test coverage is weak, but it was good enough to say "this probably works":

```
int[,] array = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 11, 12, 13 }, { 21, 22, 23 } };
var paddedArray = new ZeroPadArray<int>(array);
Debug.Assert(paddedArray[0, 0] == 0);
Debug.Assert(paddedArray[4,4] == 0);
Debug.Assert(paddedArray[2,3] == 13);
```

And, finally, for fun, I added a nice little hack to make creating these things require less typing.  When you call a method, the compiler is often able to deduce the generic type of the object from the method parameters.  This doesn't work for constructors.  That's why you need to specify `new ZeroPadArray<int>(array)` even though `array` is obviously an array of `int`.

The way to get around this is to create a second, non-generic class that you use as a static factory for creating things.  Something like:

```
public static class ZeroPadArray
{
    public static ZeroPadArray<T> Create<T>(T[,] arrayToPad)
    {
        return new ZeroPadArray<T>(arrayToPad);
    }
}
```

Now, instead of typing:

```
var paddedArray = new ZeroPadArray<int>(array);
```

you can type:

```
var paddedArray = ZeroPadArray.Create(array);
```

Saving you two characters of typing (but, you need to admit that typing the `<int>` is frustrating).

Comment: I appreciate the amount of effort you put into explaining it for me, thank you! Unfortunately, I can not yet upvote posts

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are confusing dimensions - `Array.GetLength(0)` is for the first one in access `Array[i, j]` and `Array.GetLength(1)` is for the second. Also you can simplify copy by just scanning through `Array` elements and adjusting destination indexes by one, you don't need to explicitly set others to `0` because it would be done for you (unless you are using `stackalloc` and [skipping local init](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/skip-localsinit) but I highly doubt that this is the case):

```cs
var length0 = Array.GetLength(0);
var length1 = Array.GetLength(1);
for (int i = 0; i < length0; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < length1; j++)
    {
        ArrayZeroPad[i + 1, j + 1] = Array[i, j];
    }
}
```

And in the "print" method too - `y` should be the first dimension and `x` - second:

```cs
var length = ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(0);
for (int y = 0; y < length; y++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    var i = ArrayZeroPad.GetLength(1);
    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
    {
        Console.Write(ArrayZeroPad[y, x]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this using `Array.Copy()`. If you require highest performance and the arrays are big enough, then this might be faster than explicitly copying each element:

```
public static int[,] Pad(int[,] input)
{
    int h = input.GetLength(0);
    int w = input.GetLength(1);
    var output = new int[h+2, w+2];

    for (int r = 0; r < h; ++r)
    {
        Array.Copy(input, r*w, output, (r+1)*(w+2)+1, w);
    }

    return output;
}
```

The `(r+1)*(w+2)+1` requires some explanation. `Array.Copy()` treats a 2D array as a linear 1D array, and you must specify the destination offset for the copy as an offset from the start of the 1D array (in row-major order).

Since `w` is the width of the input array and `r` is the current row of the input array, the destination for the copy of the current input row will be the output row number, `(r+1)` times the output row width `(w+2)`, plus `1` for to account for the left-hand column of `0` in the output array.

It's possible that using `Buffer.BlockCopy()` (which operates on bytes) could be even faster:

```
public static int[,] Pad(int[,] input)
{
    int h = input.GetLength(0);
    int w = input.GetLength(1);
    var output = new int[h+2, w+2];

    for (int r = 0; r < h; ++r)
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(input, r*w*sizeof(int), output, ((r+1)*(w+2)+1)*sizeof(int), w*sizeof(int));
    }

    return output;
}
```

As always, this is only worth worrying about if performance is critical, and even then only after you've benchmarked the code to verify that it actually *is* faster.