pass an array inside a multidimensional array to a function in C#
I'm trying to take a 3D array and pass an array inside there to a function, but it keeps saying an error about having the wrong number of indices inside []. I'm passing 2 values to it to return an array for a function but it's requiring me to put 3 values for a single item not an array.
public void function(int[]) {
    // does something
}

static void Main(String[] args) {
    int[,,] 3Darr = {{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}, {{10,11,12}, {13,14,15}, {16,17,18}}};
    
    function(arr[1,2]); // gets error for not passing 3 values
}


What is the type of arr? I see 3Darr declared, but not arr (I don't think 3Darr is a legal C# symbol, is it?). Consider reformatting you array initialization expression,  it's very hard to read (at least on my phone)

By the way, C# allows you to create an object that acts as if it were an array. You can create an object that acts as an int[,] or an int[,,] from any collection using indexed properties (aka indexers). Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286156/zero-padding-a-2d-array-in-c-sharp/69287712#69287712

You should use jagged array (array of array of array) int[][][] instead of 3d one int[,,]:
int[][][] arr = new int[][][] {
  new int[][] {
    new int[] {1, 2, 3},
    new int[] {4, 5, 6},
    new int[] {7, 8, 9},
  },

  new int[][] {
    new int[] {11, 12, 13},
    new int[] {14, 15, 16},
    new int[] {17, 18, 19},
  },
}; 

function(arr[1][2]);


If the dimension you want to iterate over is the last one (ie you have specified all the others) then you can use a Span<T> with the following extension functions
public static Span<T> AsSpan<T>(this Array array) =>
    MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref Unsafe.As<byte, T>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(array)), array.Length);

public static Span<T> SliceLastDim<T>(this T[,,] array, int dim1, int dim2) =>
    array.AsSpan<T>().Slice(((dim1 * array.GetLength(0)) + dim2) * array.GetLength(1), array.GetLength(2));

Then to get the row you want, just multiply the other dimensions up.
public void function(Span<int> span)
{
    // does something
}

static void Main(String[] args)
{
    int[,,] _3Darr = {{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}, {{10,11,12}, {13,14,15}, {16,17,18}}};
    var span = _3Darr.SliceLastDim(1, 2);
    function(span);
}

dotnetfiddle
A more generic solution could slice an arbitrary number of dimensions. Again, the dimensions you specify go in right-to-left, and the remaining ones are sliced. The result is a single Span<T>.
public static Span<T> Slice2D<T>(this Array array, params int[] dims)
{
    if (dims.Length >= array.Rank - 1)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Too many dimensions");

    var offset = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < dims.Length; i++)
        offset = (offset + dims[i]) * array.GetLength(i);

    var size = 1;
    for (var i = dims.Length; i < array.Rank; i++)
        size *= array.GetLength(i);

    return array.AsSpan<T>().Slice(offset, size);
}


int[,,] is an array with 3 dimensions; it can only be accessed with all 3 coordinates, and the result of that lookup will be an int, not an int[]. There is no mechanism to get a int[] from a int[,,].
I wonder if you perhaps mean instead a jagged array, so one of:

int[][][]
int[,][]
int[][,]

Alternatively, you might be able to get a Span<int> as a chunk of contiguous data from a int[,,], simply by using the ref arr[x,y,z] starting point and the number of elements. A span is broadly comparable to an array/vector (at least conceptually).

Span will only work on the last dimension, see my answer.
